# How to change orientation of file being printed with pycups

Tags: python, cups, pycups

I have this code that i want to use to print out a file in landscape, its printing, but the options don't seem to apply:

```
conn.printFile('printerName','fileName','',{"orientation-requested":"4"})
```

but it is just printing normally not in landscape.
any idea what is happening?

Comment: conn.printFile(printerName, fileName, " ", {"orientation-requested":"4", })

Comment: i'm not following, what should i replace with my code, the comma at the end of the object entry, or the double quotes?

Comment: I am assuming that neither your printer or filename are fixed strings. The name you might try with double quotes. The options which replicate -o looks fine, although I added the comma since it is passed as a dict